# Terraform using variables and other resources in modules

Tags: terraform

I am refactoring my terraform code to use modules. But I am getting alot of variable/resource not defined errors/found.

I found that I need to move my `variable [name] {}` blocks into the module. Isit impossible for modules to reference parent/another modules variables? Eg. sometimes I may have some reused variables eg. `NODE_ENV`.

---

Next ... after this, I find that it says `missing required argument`. I am just running `terraform init` because terraform says I need to do it... I tried adding `-var-file` but it does not seem to work for modules? How should I resolve this?

---

There are also alot of

```
resource 'aws_ecs_service.xxx-ecs-service' config: unknown module referenced: ecs
```

errors ... it appears I cannot reference resources the usual way anymore?

```
# ecs/ecs.tf
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xxx-ecs-task" {
  family = "${var.family}"
  container_definitions = "${data.template_file.container_defination.rendered}"
  task_role_arn = "${var.role_arn}"
  execution_role_arn = "${var.role_arn}"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  cpu = "${var.cpu}"
  memory = "${var.memory}"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  tags = "${var.tags}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "xxx-ecs-service" {
  name = "${var.service_name}"
  cluster = "${var.ecs_cluster}"
  task_definition = "${module.ecs.aws_ecs_task_definition.pinfare-ecs-task.arn}"
}
```

For the `task_defination`, I tried adding `module.ecs` since ecs is the name of my module

```
module "ecs" {
  source  = "./ecs"
  name = "ecs"
}
```

Comment: You can access only module **outputs**.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, would recommend complete directory separation.

```
module/ecs/ecs.tf
env/dev/myecs.tf
```

Below is illustration purpose and have not tested by myself.

### Configurations

#### module/ecs/ecs.tf

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "xxx-ecs-task" {
  family = "${var.family}"
  container_definitions = "${data.template_file.container_defination.rendered}"
  task_role_arn = "${var.role_arn}"
  execution_role_arn = "${var.role_arn}"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  cpu = "${var.cpu}"
  memory = "${var.memory}"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  tags = "${var.tags}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "xxx-ecs-service" {
  name = "${var.service_name}"
  cluster = "${var.ecs_cluster}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.xxx-ecs-task.arn}"
}
```

#### module/ecs/variables.tf

Define all the variables to be passed from the module user side (env/dev/myecs.tf).

```
variable "family" {
}
variable "role_arn" {
}
...
```

#### env/dev/myeecs.tf

```
module "ecs" {
  source  = "../../module/ecs"
  family = "value of family here"
  role_arn = "value of IAM role arn"
  ...
}
```

### module path

Please beware of ${path.module} as in [Paths and Embedded Files](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/create.html#paths-and-embedded-files) to specify a path to a file within a module. Confusingly both env/dev/ and module/ecs are **module** in Terraform where env/dev/ is the root module.

[Creating Modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/create.html)

> Modules in Terraform are folders with Terraform files. In fact, when you run terraform apply, the current working directory holding the Terraform files you're applying comprise what is called the root module. This itself is a valid module.

When specify a path, basically it is that within the root module. Therefore within a called module (module/ecs), prefix with ${path.module}/ so that the called module will not try to load files inside env/dev.

### Terraform Registry

I would recommend having a look at Terraform Registry, for instance [Security Group](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws/2.11.0) module to get used to how to use Terraform module. Links to GitHub are there too.